# Как заменить представление на таблицу с тем же названием?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Исторически так сложилось, что у нас на проекте сущестует представление из набора значение, выполняющее ровно ту же функцию, что и классическая таблица.

```
Create or alter view dbo.ViewName
as
select colOne, colTwo
from (values (1, 2), 
             (2, 3), 
             ...                
     ) as t(colOne, colTwo)
```

В данный момент появилась необходимость переделать это чудо на нормальную таблицу (основная цель - иметь возможность insert'ить данные, а не вбивать их руками в список values'ов). Проблема в том, что обращение к этому объекту в коде довольно много, поэтому создавать таблицу и менять ViewName на TableName во всём проекте не очень хочется.

В едином скрипте создать таблицу TempName на основе представления, грохнуть предствления, переименовать таблицу TempName -> ViewName - не вариант, поскольку вызывается оно крайне часто и мы повисним на блокировках.

Подскажите, есть ли какой-то способ решить мою проблему, не нарвавшись на проблемы, описанные выше?

Comment: *есть ли какой-то способ решить мою проблему, не нарвавшись на проблемы, описанные выше?* Что, работает 24*7 и вообще без приостановок? дропнуть вьюшку и переименовать таблицу - секунда, а то и быстрее. Уж на 30 секунд-то найдите окошко.

Comment: А зачем вообще заменять представление на таблицу? Можно ведь создать таблицу и изменить представление так, чтобы оно ссылалось на эту таблицу.

Comment: @Akina "Что, работает 24*7 и вообще без приостановок?" - да, именно так

Comment: @i-one я об это не подумал. На первый взгляд, классная идея

Comment: @i-one, оформите, пожалуйста, ответом.

Comment: что-то мне кажется что ваш код даже не заметит синхронного переименования вьюшки и новой таблицы, или если на долю секунды запросы подождут, ничего критичного не случится.

Comment: @Lobster25 то есть блокировка при alter view вас не беспокоит а блокировка при переименовании сломает все вокруг?

Comment: @teran, подскажите, а как будет работать механизм блокировок в указанном случае?

Answer (score 2):

Отличным вариантом показался ответ @i-one, оставлю тут в форме ответа:

"А зачем вообще заменять представление на таблицу? Можно ведь создать таблицу и изменить представление так, чтобы оно ссылалось на эту таблицу"